# Spaces are written as b in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to complete python challenges using JavaScript and I am stuck on my code

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

var userInput = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp.        bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj.";

for(x=0; x<userInput.length; x++){
    var key = userInput[x];
    var findinLetters = letters[letters.indexOf(key)+2];
    document.write(findinLetters);
}
```

result of the code is:

> ibhopebyoubdidntbtrundefinednslundefinedtebitbundefinedybhundefinedndbbthundefinedtsbwhundefinedtbcomputersbundefinedrebforbbdoingbitbinbundefinedybhundefinedndbisbinefficientbundefinedndbthundefinedtbsbwhybthisbtextbisbsoblongbbusingbstringbmundefinedketrundefinednsbbbisbrecommendedbbnowbundefinedpplybonbtheburlb

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 8):

`indexOf()` will return `-1` if the item was not found in the array.
You need to handle that instead of blindly adding `2` and turning all unknown characters into `b`.

You also need to handle the last two characters in the array instead of going past the end.

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is no space character in the `letters` array. So it returns -1 and you're adding 2 to that. This

```
letters.indexOf(key)+2
```

yields 1, which is the index of "b" in your array.